# Doble carga con Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

Tengo un problema al intentar ingresar a un sitio ya que es la interfaz de un equipo en ocasiones toca cargarlo hasta 3 veces para que la interfaz cargue ¿Alguno tiene alguna manera de detener la carga para volver a cargar?